# Sum of positive integers

Tags: summation

Find the sum of all positive integers x less than 100 for which (x^2)-81 is a multiple of 100? 
To do this manually would be too tedious. Also, can someone explain what the latter part of the question is saying?

Comment: Sum is 191 (ignore the 9): https://ideone.com/mXoCqZ

Comment: You can do it easily in a spreadsheet:  put the numbers 1 to 99 in a column, put $=mod(A1,100)$ in B1, copy down, use an IF statement to find the zeros, and add them up.  Or you can show some mathematical understanding as André Nicolas suggests.

Answer (score 4):

We want $(x-9)(x+9)$ to be divisible by $100$. At least one of $x-9$ and $x+9$ must be divisible by $5$. And they cannot both be, else $(x+9)-(x-9)$ would be divisible by $5$. But $18$ is not divisible by $5$.

So one of $x-9$ and $x+9$ is divisible by $25$. That gives the possibilities $x=9$, $x=34$, $x=59$, $x=84$; also $x=16$, $x=41$, $x=66$, and $x=91$.

Note all the $x$ even cases we have listed can't work, because then the product $(x-9)(x+9)$ would be odd.

Now add up the $4$ surviving numbers. We can add them "smartly" by noting that $9$ and $91$, also $59$ and $41$, add up to $100$, so our sum is $200$.

**Remark:** We could have avoided making an explicit list. The above solution is a compromise between a slick but somewhat abstract approach, and a tedious full listing approach.

Comment: But 0 is not a multiple of 100 (for x=9).

Comment: $0$ is a multiple of $100$, since $0=(0)(100)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you did, I'm sorry

Comment: I can expand on any point. To do this, I need some idea of what it is that is unclear.

Comment: @user140161 $(x-9)(x+9)=x^2-81$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\displaystyle x^2\equiv81\pmod{100}\iff \left(\frac x9\right)^2\equiv1\pmod{2^2\cdot5^2}\ \ \ \ (1)$

$$\iff\left(\frac x9\right)^2\equiv1\pmod{2^2}\  \ \ \ (2)$$ and $$\iff\left(\frac x9\right)^2\equiv1\pmod{5^2}\  \ \ \  (3)$$

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104961/number-of-solutions-of-x2-1-in-mathbbz-n-mathbbz), $(2),(3)$ each has $2$ solutions

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624504/congruences-of-the-form-x2-a-equiv-0-mod-pq) or the famous [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), we can show that there will be $2\cdot2=4$ in-congruent  solutions $\pmod{25\cdot4}$

Now, $\displaystyle (100-y)^2=100^2-200y+y^2\equiv y^2\pmod{100}$

So, if $y_1$ is a solution of $(1),$ so will be $100-y_1$ leading to a sum $y_1+100-y_1=100$

As there are four solutions i.e., two pairs, the sum has to be $2\cdot100$

We can replace $100$ here with $p^a\cdot q^b$ where $p,q$ are primes and $a,b$ are positive  integers

Comment: i am not familiar with the terms you are using

Comment: @user140161, please find the edited version

Comment: I am not familiar with number theory and this question is from a competition for 11th and 12th graders. I am unfamiliar with the term mod and the approach you have used to solve this. Please suggest topics I should read up on to understand your solution. Thanks!